# Django- Make python object persist during a session

Tags: python, django, session, caching, fsm

I have a class which has an FSM. I want store variables and transition through the FSM states based on repeated interaction with the user. It's something like a chat interface.

So, as per my requirements, I have a object that is not part of the database (not included in models but defined in a custom python file). I want to create an **class instance per-user-per-session** and have it persist through the session.

I thought this could be done via session variables in Django but I read that you can't keep class instances as session variables (may be possible by pickling, but I read in multiple places that its discouraged). It maybe possible using cache system, but I do not know how to go about it.

Can someone give me some solid directions on what the best method would be and how to implement it?

---

I have not included any code, because I think the question is more in terms of knowledge than just implementation, but I can provide some example code if required.

Comment: I don't see why you do not store the FSM state in the database, it looks a lot less cumbersome than pickling, unpickling, etc. Imagine two users concurrently changing state, that could result in race conditions, etc. You can see databases as a persistent storage, that actually has been designed to aim to prevent such clashes.

Comment: The only "memory" an FSM has, is its state, so you need to encode it (for example assign numbers to each state), and then each time look at the transitions from that specific state.

Comment: Hi. Are you suggesting that I include this FSM class in my `models.py`, create instances for each user and retrieve it for each user based on their request? And transition from state to state using a typical django view?
One worry I have is whether it will affect performance, having to run database queries for each transition. As it is supposed to be like a chat interface, it will need to be fast.

Comment: Well not per se the FSM class. You only need to store, for every user, what the state is the user is in. Typically that is an integer. For example user 123 is in state 5. Then you write logic that understands what state `5` is, and what possible transitions can be made (based on certain triggers). For instance later if a user makes a transaction, you write that that user is now in state `7`.

Comment: Okay. So you are saying I store the state as a session variable and change it when transitions occur, right? So in this case how would I handle the FSM? Will it be in a `view` and be instantiated each time? Suppose the user123 is in state `5` now and i got a trigger i will go to a `view` and create another FSM instance and set it to state `5` and provide the trigger and store the new state in the session variable which held `5`?